# Can I use kvoptions - DeclareStringOption with Spanish characters?

Tags: spanish, kvoptions

I've just discovered kvoptions package to pass options to my sty file. I want to pass the title of the document but it contains Spanish characters (á,é,í,ó,ú) and it can't be rendered well. I use this characters perfect in my document, but no with \style@variable command. How can I use it? I'm a newbie with LaTeX. This is the document

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[titulo={Práctica 1: Búsquedas con trayectorias simples}]{estilo}

 \begin{document}
   \maketitle 

 \end{document}
```

This is the estilo.sty file.

```
\ProvidesPackage{estilo}

%Comandos para configurar el idioma
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Necesario para el uso de las comillas latinas.
\usepackage{geometry} % Used to adjust the document margins

%Package for options management
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareStringOption[MetaHeuristicas]{titulo}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

%Importante que esta sea la última órden del preámbulo
\usepackage{hyperref}
   \hypersetup{
     pdftitle=\estilo@titulo,
     pdfauthor={Me},
     unicode,
     breaklinks=true,  % so long urls are correctly broken across lines
     colorlinks=true,
     urlcolor=blue,
     linkcolor=darkorange,
     citecolor=darkgreen
     }
```

Output

[image: Output]

EDIT: If I load [utf8]{inputenc} before loading estilo.sty, I get this

[image: Output2]

Comment: You should, at the least, have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` before loading `estilo`

Comment: If I do that I get this http://imgur.com/5y9gluI . It's better but it's no readable :(. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package options of `\usepackage` are first read by LaTeX:

- The 8-bit bytes of the input file have category code 12 (other) like digits.
  `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` makes these bytes active. The active character bytes then decode the bytes to get the macros for the Unicode character representation.
- LaTeX expands the options the hard way (`\edef`) assuming options are only simple ASCII letters and digits. Package `kvoptions-patch` patches the LaTeX option parsing to support arbitrary macros in the values of key value settings *without* expanding them.

The document start now looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kvoptions-patch}
\usepackage[titulo={Práctica 1: Búsquedas con trayectorias simples}]{estilo}
```

(If `kvoptions-patch` is loaded before `\documentclass` via `\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}`, then macros can also be used in option values for global options.)

> [image: Result]

A more robust interface regarding the option processing is to use a macro  after the package is loaded, e.g.:

```
\usepackage{estilo}
\estilosetup{titulo={...}}
```

Comment: It works like a charm. One Line Solution :D!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When the option to `estilo` is read in, the package `inputenc` has not yet been loaded. You can fix the string by using `\scantokens`

### `estilo.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{estilo}

%Comandos para configurar el idioma
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Necesario para el uso de las comillas latinas.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry} % Used to adjust the document margins

%Package for options management
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareStringOption[MetaHeuristicas]{titulo}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\@ifundefined{estilo@titulo}{}{%
  \scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter\def\expandafter\estilo@titulo\expandafter{\estilo@titulo}}%
}

%Importante que esta sea la última órden del preámbulo
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   pdftitle=\estilo@titulo,
   pdfauthor={Me},
   unicode,
   breaklinks=true,  % so long urls are correctly broken across lines
   colorlinks=true,
   urlcolor=blue,
   linkcolor=darkorange,
   citecolor=darkgreen
}
```

### `test.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[titulo={Práctica 1: Búsquedas con trayectorias simples}]{estilo}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

### Info window

[image]

### Output of `pdfinfo`

```
> pdfinfo -enc UTF-8 test.pdf
Title:          Práctica 1: Búsquedas con trayectorias simples
Subject:        
Keywords:       
Author:         Me
Creator:        LaTeX with hyperref package
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.16
CreationDate:   Mon Apr  4 18:45:39 2016
ModDate:        Mon Apr  4 18:45:39 2016
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4) (rotated 0 degrees)
File size:      36484 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

Comment: Thank you too, but the other solution works perfect for me :D!