# How to define a string variable with diacritics to my own package (.sty)

Tags: packages, package-writing, package-options

I try to add a variable title string to my own package 'MyStyle.sty'.

'MyStyle.sty' just contains some used packages, pdf settings and commands for a style guide / corporate identity.

**Document.tex**

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=a4,headings=normal,titlepage=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[tileString=My title]{MyStyle}
...
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

**MyStyle.sty**

```
\usepackage{scrhack}
...
\hypersetup{ pdftitle={\titleString} }
...
\endinput
```

How to add this **titleString** variable to my package? I need the solution to work with non-ASCII characters, like `ä`, `ü`, `ö` as well. I found something like `\DeclareOptions` but can't use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LaTeX's `\DeclareOption` doesn't work with key-value pairs. That is, options like `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt` are allowed, but an option `fontsize=<10 or 11 or 12>` wouldn't work.

There are a few packages that implement this key-value scheme. Here's a solution using `kvoptions`:

**MyStyle.sty**

```
\RequirePackage{scrhack}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}% load kvoptions

\SetupKeyvalOptions{%
  family=mysty@,% define the family and prefix of the options
  prefix=mysty@}

\DeclareStringOption{titleString}% declare a key-value option 'titleString'

% make kvoptions read the options passed to the package and evaluate them.
\ProcessKeyvalOptions{mysty@}

% you need hyperref to use hypersetup
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

% the value given to the option is stored in \mysty@titleString
\hypersetup{ pdftitle={\mysty@titleString} }

\endinput
```

**document.tex**

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=a4,headings=normal,titlepage=true]{scrbook}

% you need braces to preserve spaces
\usepackage[titleString={My title}]{MyStyle}

\begin{document}

hello

\end{document}
```

---

## Update:

### Using options with non-ASCII characters

When you try to use options with non-ASCII characters you'll get a lot of warnings from `hyperref` saying:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `<something>' on input line <somewhere>.
```

then where you had the non-ASCII letters you'll have some numbers.

As explained by Heiko Oberdiek [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302470/134574), this happens when the `\usepackage` command passes the options to the package.

Quoting Oberdiek:

> The 8-bit bytes of the input file have category code 12 (other) like digits. `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` makes these bytes active. The active character bytes then decode the bytes to get the macros for the Unicode character representation.
>
> LaTeX expands the options the hard way (`\edef`) assuming options are only simple ASCII letters and digits.

This forced expansion of the active Unicode characters generates the sequence of commands that `hyperref` rejects when adding the metadata to the pdf.

> Package `kvoptions-patch` patches the LaTeX option parsing to support arbitrary macros in the values of key value settings *without* expanding them.

So you have to load `kvoptions-patch` prior to calling your `MyStyle` package:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=a4,headings=normal,titlepage=true]{scrbook}
% This is necessary for unicode characters in pdfTeX
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% This patches LaTeX's package loading to allow unicode strings.
\usepackage{kvoptions-patch}

% you need braces to preserve spaces
\usepackage[titleString={größenordnungsmäßig}]{MyStyle}

\begin{document}

hello

\end{document}
```

---

Of course, this is needed only if you use pdfTeX. XeTeX and LuaTeX have unicode support by default and don't require this workaround.

Comment: Perfect solution for me! +1 But is there a possibility to add german mutated vowels like ä, ü, ö in my title string? I always get a 'Token not allowed in PDF string' warning

Comment: @Passe Hmmm... Something wrong is not right here. When the diacritics are passed to the package something gets messed up. I'm trying to figure out where and why this is happening. As soon as I find out I'll ping you here :)

Comment: @Passe Done :) You have to load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (which I believe you already have because of the warnings you get) and `\usepackage{kvoptions-patch}` to allow the unicode strings in the options.