# Using utf8 characters in kvoptions

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, kvoptions

The problem is actually quite simple yet I haven't found a working solution.

In the `kvoptions` package, you can define option keys for custom packages which take strings as a value, e.g.

```latex
% `mysty.sty`, assuming it is correctly saved in `$TEXMFHOME` and indexed
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mysty}

% Preload input encoding and language, I'm German
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Declare option, the value is then saved in `\mysty@sometitle`
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareStringOption{sometitle}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\title{\mysty@sometitle}
\author{me}
\date{\today}

\endinput
```

```latex
% `myfile.tex`
\documentclass{article}

% Note the German *umlaut* `ü`, a non-ASCII character
\usepackage[sometitle={Programmiervorkurs für Erstis}]{mysty}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

This would produce error messages, mostly of the form `Missing } inserted` (right before `\maketitle`) and `To many }'s`, whereas the (surprisingly) compiled PDF file looks really weird
[image: Weird PDF]

*Is there any way to fix that, i.e. let `kvoptions` understand `utf8` input?*

---

Actually, a similar question was asked here already.

> [Can I use kvoptions - DeclareStringOption with Spanish characters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/302460)

The problem is that both given solutions don't work anymore (at least for me):

1. The original package author @[Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) provided the `kvoptions-patch` package, which can be loaded before `mysty` (see post for more). This package would solve all problems, but since version 3.14 of `kvoptions`, this package isn't supported anymore for LaTeX versions from October 2020 or newer (see [`kvoptions`' documentation](https://mirror.informatik.hs-fulda.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/kvoptions/kvoptions.pdf), chapter 4.1, p.12).
2. User @[egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) provided another solution by using `\scantokens`, which in my case would translate to

   ```latex
   % Right after `\ProcessKeyvalOptions*`
   \@ifundefined{mysty@sometitle}{}{%
       \scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter\def\expandafter\mysty@sometitle\expandafter{\mysty@sometitle}}%
   }
   ```

   I don't know much about low-level TeX/LaTex commands and such, but the provided solution doesn't work. Even without `\@ifundefined...` (won't `\mysty@sometitle` be defined after giving the option a value??), only the word *immediate* would disappear from the PDF (see image above).
3. Inspired by @egreg, I tried something like this:

   ```latex
   % After `\ProcessKeyvalOptions*`
   \renewcommand{\mysty@sometitle}{\scantokens{\mysty@sometitle\empty}}
   ```

   But instead of the title, the PDF contains only `@sometitle` as the title. I guess the `@` symbol ends the token list (which I don't want). Storing in a temporary variable doesn't help too. I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This should work "soon" but will take a few updates.

`kvoptions` hasn't yet been updated to use the "raw" options passed from the document, the classical option argument gets passed through an edef and utf-8 characters get mangled, as you saw.

So for now add

```
\expandafter\let\csname opt@mysty.sty\expandafter\endcsname
\csname @raw@opt@mysty.sty\endcsname
```

To `mysty.sty` before processing the arguments.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mysty}

%  replace the option string by the raw option string (requires a newish latex)
\expandafter\let\csname opt@mysty.sty\expandafter\endcsname
\csname @raw@opt@mysty.sty\endcsname

% Preload input encoding and language, I'm German
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not required unless you have an old latex.

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Declare option, the value is then saved in `\mysty@sometitle`
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareStringOption{sometitle}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\title{\mysty@sometitle}
\author{me}
\date{\today}

\endinput
```

That should be enough but unfortunately the raw option string still gets processed at one point generating an error. That is fixed in the sources for the next LaTeX release (due Novermber 2021) but you can already use `pdflatex-dev` pre-release which includes this fix.

So `pdflatex-dev myfile` with `mysty.sty` as above produces the output shown with no error.

Comment: That's good news! So with the next release we'll be able to grab `\usepackage` option arguments before they get expanded? Is the same valid for `l3keys2e` as well?

Comment: @gusbrs the last few releases have saved the arguments as `@raw@....`  but don't actually use them, compatibility concerns make changing the default option handler hard, but gradually extension packages can use these koma script does already I think as does skillmon's set of packages, I will update kvoptions at some point.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea we already had access to it. And, indeed, changing the default there is bound to be a delicate operation. I'm looking forward to see it coming one day though.  :-)

Comment: I've checked `l3keys2e` and, as far as I can tell, it does not use `@raw@opt@` at all. I'll check what Skillmon does with it.

Comment: Thanks, it works in my more complex project! Note that the magic hack must appear *in front of all other packages* (including `babel` and `fontenc`), not just `kvoptions`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What is the status now on raw option strings? I've updated and my Latex distribution and can compile my file with `pdflatex` instead of `pdflatex-dev` now. But do I still need the `@raw@...` part?

Comment: @Gargantuar yes, we are working on a plan, but not rolled out yet